# A post that doesn't exist is shown on the "Top network posts" section on this user profile on English Language & Usage Stack Exchange

Tags: bug, profile-page

A post that doesn't exist is shown on the "Top network posts" section on this [user profile](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/277355/lbf). The title is called "6", and the URL of the post leads to this [non-existent page](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/-2147480236/184031#184031).

[image]

Comment: I'm not certain what criteria are being used here to determine "exact duplicate", but in the case of the other question, the phantom post doesn't exist, in this case it does, but the link is broken. Vis a vis: [here it is](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/184030/what-does-boot-mean-here/184031#184031). If you edit you post to include this info it may get reopened as a not-duplicate.

Comment: The URL from this post is `https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/-2147480236/184031#184031` and the URL from the duplicate is `https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/-2147482643/330386#330386` - you'll notice that they both have the same overflow number in them. This looks like someone isn't checking for a valid user ID before forming the URL, so it breaks when a question has been migrated. This does look to be the same  problem.